# Why does requiring a file up one level, outside the current directory, show "not found" on php cron?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

**test3.php**

```
<?php
require("../includes/config.php.inc"); 
echo "done";
?>
```

Works fine when I launch it in my web browser (it says done), but when I use
`/usr/local/bin/php -f /home3/site/public_html/order/functions/test3.php` to run the same file as a Cpanel cron job, I get an email saying there was an error.

> Warning: require(../includes/config.php.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/site/public_html/order/functions/cron_renewal.php on line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference lies in the current directory is different when the script is run from browser or from cron. Try using `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` instead. For example, try:

```
<?php
require(__DIR__ . "/../includes/config.php.inc"); 
echo "done";
?>
```

In my opinion this is the most flexible way, since you don't have to make your cron command to complicated (you just run the script) and you can move the sources along the harddrive and you don't have to hardcode any paths.

---

edit: the same approach applies to other platforms, such as python, ruby, etc. ;) this is just a "good practice" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
cd /home3/site/public_html/order/functions/;/usr/local/bin/php -f test3.php
```

The includes are relative to the current working directory.
(Maybe this is not the correct directory... You should cd to the file's parent directory which is working from web.)

Comment: This could work (if the paths are ok) but I think it's not flexible. Imho it's better if the script would use relative paths - then your cron command is easier and you can move your project within the harddrive and it's easier.